# How to check 2 -3 conditions in correct way?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have to display an popup windows to clients, when **mobilePhone** and **profileDetails** are not added, both popups should be displayed one-by-one (when 1 is done, then 2 should be displayed, if both are done, no popups)

So, I have the following code:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
    if (userDTO.getMobile().isEmpty() && artistDetailsDTO.getCategoryID().isEmpty() {
    show popup to fill up a profile
    }
}

if(userDTO.getMobile().isEmpty() && artistDetailsDTO.getCategory_id().matches("[0-9]+")) {
show popup to add a mobile phone
}
```

When user fills up categoryID, and open this page again, user still getting a popup to fill up his profile.

But above I have mentioned **&&artistDetailsDTO.getCategory_id().matches("[0-9]+")) {**

As I understood it should appears when both conditions are true, but in my case mobile is empty, but categoryID not empty.

Or I did something wrong?

What I expect, that onCreateView

I should check:

```
1. if mobileIsEmpty + categoryIDisEmpty == show popup to fill profile.    
2. if mobileIsEmpty + categoryID**NOT**Empty == show popup to fill mobile    
3. if mobileIs**NOT**empty + categoryID**NOT**Empty == show nothing
```

I did a lot of variants .. && , ^ , & , ! non of them are worked correctly.

Looking forward, to have any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: not showing what you tried won't help us find your problem

Comment: updated a bit question ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So do that

```
if(mobileIsEmpty){
  if(categoryIDisEmpty ){
    show popup to fill profile
  }else {
     how popup to fill mobile 
   }
}else if(categoryID**NOT**Empty)  {
show nothing
}
```

Last if you can not use if you haven't other conditions